# How to declare a struct in a header file and initialize it in another .h file?

Tags: c, struct, header, initialization, declaration

I am a beginner in programming in C, and I am trying to make my code as modular as possible, so I want to declare a structure,

```
enum TRANSMITER_INT
{
    DISABLE,
    ENABLE
};
typedef struct Config
{
  enum TRANSMITER_INT TRANSMITER ;
}Config;
```

and initialize the values of this structure in a different header file, so the user will only have access to this file only to configure the module with it.

```
Config global_Config  =
     {   
          DISABLE  ,
     };
```

But when I Build the project it keeps giving me this error

`expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'global_Config'`

Any tips on how I can get this to work?

Comment: It seems like something is missing from this post, since you don't have anything here named `global_USART_Config`.  I also don't see anything named `TRANSMITER_DISABLE`, so that's probably not going to work right either.

Comment: Is there anything else in the include file after the definition of the struct?  If you declare a second struct but forget to put a ; at the end, you'd get an error just like this.  And you do have the #include for your header file *before* you declare global_Config, right?